# Developing a database to store 100-dimensional image embeddings along with their paths

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, nearest-neighbor

Suppose we want to design a database to store images represented in a vector format (each image is stored as a 100-dimensional vector). The goal here is to store image embeddings along with their paths so that we can use the embedding to find image neighbors, which helps in image retrieval. Once we find the neighbors to images, I would like to return back and display images, and that is why I need to store image paths as well in the database.

The KD-tree data structure is good to start for the nearest neighbors search, but it suffers from dimensionality issues given we have a vector of dimension equal to 100.

**First question**: Can you please let me know what you think about this design strategy and what would you recommend as an alternative to KD-tree to deal with high dimensional input?

**Second question**: Is it easy to find sophisticated nearest neighbor search in Oracle database for example?

Comment: @J.D. I am trying to build a database to search for images in an efficient manner. Each image is represented by a 100-dimensional vector along with its path. Why do I need an image path? So that after applying the nearest search neighbor on an image vector of size 100 in order to retrieve similar images, I can then display all found similar images (based on the result of the nearest neighbor search). Hopefully, this helps more. I am looking though for the nearest search algorithm that scales to large dimensions and also design strategy advice for the database if that is possible, please?

Comment: @J.D. I am not sure about table design but the only data I have is 1) image embedding (vector representation of dimension 100) and 2) image path to tell where the image is in the system). That is all for the data. 

What do I want? Image vectors for similar images should have a close Euclidean distance while images that are dissimilar should have a far Euclidean distance. I want to cluster images based on their embedding and retrieve them quickly from the database. I am not sure what you think now, please. For example, image embeddings for animals should have a very close distance.

Comment: @J.D. In this article https://medium.com/criteo-engineering/introducing-autofaiss-an-automatic-k-nearest-neighbor-indexing-library-at-scale-c90842005a11, they mentioned K-NN index, which is part of what I am looking at in this post. Can you please add details what is this K-NN index?

Answer (score -1):

There are already open source vector databases that will do this. Check out [Milvus](https://milvus.io/) and the associated [GitHub repo](https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus).

I work at Zilliz - one of the maintainers of [Open Source Milvus](https://milvus.io/docs/overview.md) with the https://lfaidata.foundation/projects/milvus/.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for something to build if possible not a tool.

Comment: Disclosure must go in the post body, not a comment. Rules: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/promotion